# Symbolic contour integral evaluation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Can anyone help with the evaluation of the following contour integral :

$$\oint\limits_C \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy.$$

Where the contour $C$ is given by:

[image]

What I am looking for is how to split the contour integral in to normal integral.

Comment: More information is needed. It is not clear at all what to do here... Also, should the $dt$ be a $dy$?

Comment: There is no point in offering a bounty for the problem if you won't tell anybody what the question is.

Comment: What do you know about functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ ?

Comment: They are non-linear functions of $x$ and $y$. I am really not seeking for the complet evaluation. I just need the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the start is following

$$
\oint\limits_C \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy = 
\int\limits_{C_1} \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy 
+ \int\limits_{C_2} \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy 
+ \int\limits_{C_3} \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy 
+ \int\limits_{C_4} \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy.
$$
Were $C_i$ - sides of the rectangle.

To calculate these line integrals we we parametrize each line. For instance lower bound $C_1(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, 
where $x(t)=t$, $y(t) = j-\Delta y$ and parameter $t\in[i-\Delta x/2,i+\Delta x/2]$ Note that $dy(t) = 0$. Then we write
$$
\int\limits_{C_1} \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy =
 \int\limits_{i-\Delta x/2}^{i+\Delta x/2} \phi(x(t),y(t))\,dx(t)+\psi(x(t),y(t))\,dy(t) =
\int\limits_{i-\Delta x/2}^{i+\Delta x/2} \phi(t,j-\Delta y)\,dt.
$$

The key of this problem (I suppose) that contour is small. So, for example
$$
\int\limits_{C_1} \phi(x,y)\,dx+\psi(x,y)\,dy = 
\int\limits_{C_1} \phi(x,y)\,dx= 
\int\limits_{i-\Delta x/2}^{i+\Delta x/2} \phi(t,j-\Delta y)\,dt\approx
 \varphi(i,j-\Delta y)\Delta x.
$$

Comment: can you please explain how did you get $ \int\limits_{i-\Delta x/2}^{i+\Delta x/2} \phi(t,j-\Delta y)\,dt $?. Was this some sort of variable change?

Comment: It is the definition of how to calculate line integral, but it also variable change. I add the example for $C_1$.